# How to mock new Date() which is called inside a function?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

Below is my Js code

```
export const getCurrentTimestamp = () => {
const d = new Date();
const date = d.toISOString().split('T')[0];
const time = d.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
return `${date} ${time}`;
};
```

So I need to mock new Date(). Below is the test code

```
test('verifying current timestamp', () => {
  const now = new Date('2021-08-04T11:01:58.135Z');
  jest.spyOn(global, 'Date').mockImplementation(() => now);
  expect(getCurrentTimestamp()).toBe('2021-08-04 11:01:58');
});
```

But the test is failing. May i know the reason

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Actually "d.toTimeString()" was converting the mocked timestamp to local timezone. SO i did the below change

```
const getCurrentTimestamp = () => {
const d = new Date();
console.log(d)
const date = d.toISOString().split('T')[0];
const time = d.toISOString().split('T')[1].split('.')[0]; // here is the change
return `${date} ${time}`;
};
```